# mapAsync type mismatch; found : Unit required: scala.concurrent.Future

Tags: scala, akka

My this piece of code complaining about `type mismatch; found: Unit required: scala.concurrent.Future` , whereas I am returning a `Future` . I am very new in Scala not sure what I am missing here .

```
val records: List[CommittableRecord[Either[Throwable, MyEvent]]] = ???
records.mapAsync(1){ x => 
        val res = (x.value match {
          case Right(event:MyEvent) =>  
              val future = getTask(event.get("task").getOrElse(""))
              //future => Future[Try[Int]]
              val k = future.map {                  
                   case Success(value) => value 
                   case Failure(exception) => 0                   
              }
              //k => Future[Int]
        })
      }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variable assignment returns `Unit`, just remove `val k =`  or put `k` at the end